# (C++) Disabling Alt commands in Windows

Tags: c++, input, alt

I'm making a program that needs to block all input during a short critical section. I used BlockInput, but it still allows the user to use hotkeys like Ctrl+Alt+F1 or Ctrl+Alt+F2 (switching taskbar in both displays). It is crucial that the user is not able to use these two hotkeys.

I read some things about a hook, but I'm not sure where to start with this solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529577/disable-control-alt-delete-and-windowswin-key-in-windows-7-using-win32-app

Answer (score 1):

A keyboard hook could do the trick - check out [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx). Note that it gets tricky on 64-bit systems.

But may I suggest simply setting your process/thread priority to some ludicrously high value? Windows will really favor your process then, and at the highest settings even keyboard and mouse stopped working - I found that out the hard way. :)