# How to prevent the functions of Alt + Tab , Alt + Escape and Other shortcut functions

Tags: vb.net, keyboard-shortcuts

I have this code to prevent closing a windows form using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>

```
Private Sub Form4_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.Alt = True And e.KeyCode = Keys.F4 Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I am still looking to prevent the user by pressing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>. I try this code but its not working.

```
  If e.Alt = True And e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
```

**and**

```
If e.Alt = True And e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
```

Is there any solution on how to prevent these shortcuts functions in vb.net?. Specially the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>

Comment: Are we assuming this is a kiosk type application?

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+Del cannot be intercepted. Windows will not allow it to be trapped. This has been discussed here many times before. Do some searching on *Prevent Ctrl+Alt+Del*

Comment: @LarsTech yes. I have an application like that.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/4529577/62576

Comment: this may help https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/itpro/windows/manage/set-up-a-kiosk-for-windows-10-for-desktop-editions